# What if the unstaking time is shortened to several minutes?

Tags: proof-of-stake, eth-2.0, staking

I am wondering What if the unstaking time is shortened to several minutes? not several days or weeks? Is there any problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that it gives some leeway to malevolent actors that could make *slashable actions* and leave before being punished for it!

If you're curious, currently the lock period are descirbed [here](https://notes.ethereum.org/7CFxjwMgQSWOHIxLgJP2Bw#A-note-on-Ethereum-20-phase-0-validator-lifecycle):

> The unslashed and exited validators need to wait for 2^8 epochs (~27 hours) to become withdrawable

> The slashed and exited validators suffer from a lock-in period of
> 2^13 epochs (~36 days) before they become withdrawable.